# Как безопасно перенести обновлённый атлас спрайтов в tile palette и при том сохранить уровень?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я делаю платформер в юнити. У меня есть атлас спрайтов, в который я добавил несколько спрайтов, заменил старый на новый перенёс его в tile palette на место старого и все спрайты перепутались.
Как мне правильно заменить тайлсет и при этом не потерять уровень?

Comment: Просто подмени изображение в папке.

Comment: заменить атлас спрайтов легко, как перенести его в тайлмап?